# How to display user name from collection not form in flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am trying to display the name of users after the login only using email and password as input. Users already have their names, email, and password within the collection in which of course I can use all of them to authenticate within a login form with three inputs.

But trying to use a session to retrieve data from the collection and form authenticating from the form with the collection I am having issues to display the `session['name']` in the seller central after the login.

I have already used an if statement to pass the name within the session but I think I am doing it wrong.

Login function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        user = mongo.db.user
        login_user = user.find_one({
        #'name': request.form.get('username'),
        'email': request.form.get('email'), 
        'password':request.form.get('password'
        )})

        if login_user:
            session['email'] = request.form.get('email')
            session['name'] = mongo.db.user.find_one({'name': 'name'})
            return redirect(url_for('user'))

        return 'Invalid username or password combination'
```

Login form:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="row justify-content-center card-deck">

    <div class="col-md-4 card card-body">

        <!-- Vertical navbar -->
        {% if session['email'] != None %}
        <div class="vertical-nav bg-white" id="sidebar">
            <div class="py-4 px-3 mb-4 bg-light">
                <div class="media d-flex align-items-center"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mhmd/image/upload/v1556074849/avatar-1_tcnd60.png" alt="..." width="65" class="mr-3 rounded-circle img-thumbnail shadow-sm">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="m-0">{{ session['name'] }}</h4>
                        <p class="font-weight-light text-muted mb-0">Seller</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <p class="text-gray font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3 small pb-4 mb-0">Main</p>

            <ul class="nav flex-column bg-white mb-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope  mr-3 text-dark fa-fw"></i>
                {{session['email']}}
            </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark font-italic bg-light">
                <i class="fa fa-th-large mr-3 text-dark fa-fw"></i>
                Products
            </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark font-italic">
                <i class="fa fa-address-card mr-3 text-dark fa-fw"></i>
                About
            </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark font-italic">
                <i class="fa fa-cubes mr-3 text-primary fa-fw"></i>
                Services
            </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark font-italic">
                <i class="fa fa-comments-o mr-3 text-primary fa-fw"></i>
                Comments
            </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <p class="text-gray font-weight-bold text-uppercase px-3 small py-4 mb-0">Charts</p>
            {% endif %}
            <----THE REST OF THE FORM--->
{% endblock %}
```

It is displaying the `session['email']` but not the `session['name']` in which I want to display on the user name after he or she be logged in. It must be something simple but I can't find.

Comment: have you already tried something like `session['name'] = login_user.name` ?

Comment: @PRMoureu yes I get a ``` AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'

Traceback (most recent call last)```.

Comment: sorry, not used to pymongo, if it's a dict  it should  be `session['name'] = login_user['name']`

Comment: Yes, that was the answer. It worked @PRMoureu. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already select the `login_user` above in the code, you can directly use the members of this user object :

```
if login_user:
    session['email'] = login_user['email']
    session['name'] = login_user['name']
    return redirect(url_for('user'))
```